# Why is the correlation one when values differ?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, data-science, correlation, pearson-correlation

I have a dataframe `book_matrix` with users as rows, books as columns, and ratings as values. When I use `corrwith()` to compute the correlation between 'The Lord of the Rings' and 'The Silmarillion' the result is `1.0`, but the values are clearly different.

[image]

The non-null values [10, 3] and [10, 9] have correlation `1.0`. I would expect them to be exactly the same when the correlation is equal to one. How can this happen?

Comment: For your row 184, I think you need to save it to a new dataframe before you perform the correlation?

Comment: @KevinChoonLiangYew Sorry, I don't understand. What do you mean by "row 184"?

Comment: Sorry for my bad English, I mean input 184

Comment: @KevinChoonLiangYew Could you please provide the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correlation means the values have a certain relationship with one another, for example linear combination of factors. Here's an illustration:

```
import pandas as pd
  
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"A":[1, 2, 3, 4], 
                    "B":[5, 8, 4, 3],
                    "C":[10, 4, 9, 3]})
  
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"A":[2, 4, 6, 8],
                    "B":[-5, -8, -4, -3],
                    "C":[4, 3, 8, 5]})

df1.corrwith(df2, axis=0)

A    1.000000
B   -1.000000
C    0.395437
dtype: float64
```

So you can see that `[1, 2, 3, 4]` and `[2, 4, 6, 8]` have correlation `1.0`

The next column `[5, 8, 4, 3]` and `[-5, -8, -4, -3]` have extreme negative correlation `-1.0`

In the last column, `[10, 4, 9, 3]` and `[4, 3, 8, 5]` are somewhat correlated `0.395437`, because both exhibits high-low-high-low sequence but with varying vertical scaling factors.

So in your case both books 'The Lord of the Rings' and 'The Silmarillion' only has 2 ratings each, and both ratings are having high-low sequence. Even if I illustrate with more data points, they have the same vertical scaling factor.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"A": [10, 3, 10, 3, 10, 3],
                    "B": [10, 3, 10, 3, 10, 3]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"A": [10, 9, 10, 9, 10, 9],
                    "B": [10, 10, 10, 9, 9, 9]})

df1.corrwith(df2, axis=0)

A    1.000000
B    0.333333
dtype: float64
```

So you can see that `[10, 3, 10, 3, 10, 3]` and `[10, 9, 10, 9, 10, 9]` are also correlated perfectly at `1.0`.

But if I rearrange the sequence a little, `[10, 3, 10, 3, 10, 3]` and `[10, 10, 10, 9, 9, 9]` are not perfectly correlated anymore at `0.333333`

So going forward, you need more data, and more variations in the data! Hope that helps